# Append Multiple Parameters to Single URL with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I've almost got this working, but having one issue. I am building a URL for an add to cart link based on quantities selected from fields. As the quantities are selected, parameters are added to the end of the link with a variation ID and quantity. The issue I am having is that if I select a quantity and then go back and change it, it adds the same variation twice, where I want it to overwrite it and only have it once.

Here is a copy of some sample code I am working on:

```
<table id="order">
<tr>
  <td class="id" data-id="3">Adult</td>
  <td class="price" data-price="50.00">50.00</td>
  <td class="qty">
  <select name="qty">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="id" data-id="4">Child</td>
  <td class="price" data-price="30.00">30.00</td>
  <td class="qty">
    <select name="qty">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="total">
$0.00
</div>

<div id="link">
  <a href="https://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=1370">Test Link</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.qty select').change(function() {
    var calculated_total_sum = 0;
    var parameter = '';
    var href = $("#link a").attr("href");
    
    $("#order .qty select").each(function () {
      var id = $(this).closest('td').prevAll('.id').attr('data-id');
      var price = $(this).closest('td').prevAll('.price').attr('data-price');
      var qty = $(this).val();
      var subtotal = price * qty
      if (qty > 0) {
        calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(subtotal);
        parameter += '&variation_id='+id+'&quantity='+qty;
      }
      
    });
    
    $('#link a').attr('href', href + parameter);
    $("#total").html(calculated_total_sum);
    
  });
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/riotactstudios/da84zt1L/44/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the variation is already included in the URL, and if so, remove it before appending the updated quantity:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.qty select').change(function() {
      var calculated_total_sum = 0;
      var parameter = '';
      var href = $("#link a").attr("href");

      $("#order .qty select").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).closest('td').prevAll('.id').attr('data-id');
        var price = $(this).closest('td').prevAll('.price').attr('data-price');
        var qty = $(this).val();
        var subtotal = price * qty
        if (qty > 0) {
          calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(subtotal);
          var variation_param = '&variation_id='+id+'&quantity='+qty;
          href = href.replace(new RegExp('&variation_id=' + id + '&quantity=\\d+'), '');
          parameter += variation_param;
        }
      });

      $('#link a').attr('href', href + parameter);
      $("#total").html(calculated_total_sum);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="order">
<tr>
  <td class="id" data-id="3">Adult</td>
  <td class="price" data-price="50.00">50.00</td>
  <td class="qty">
  <select name="qty">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="id" data-id="4">Child</td>
  <td class="price" data-price="30.00">30.00</td>
  <td class="qty">
    <select name="qty">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="total">
$0.00
</div>

<div id="link">
  <a href="https://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=1370">Test Link</a>
</div>
```